# Ошибка foreach в контроллере

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```php
function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required',
        ]);

        $house = House::query()->create([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'description' => $request->get('description'),
        ]);
       
        foreach($request->getOtchetsForHouse as $otchet) {

            $house->getOtchetsForHouse()->create([
                'file_name' => $otchet['file_name'],
                'link_file' => $otchet['link_file'],
             ]);

        }
        return redirect()->route('house.index');
```

Добавил foreach для того чтобы при создании дома, я мог добавлять еще дополнительные поля, а именно ссылку и название файла.
В моделе код такой:
**Otchet Model**

```php
 public function getOtchetsForHouse()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Otchet::class);
    }
```

**House Model**

```php
 public function house()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(House::class);
    }
```

Выводит данные на страницу show, значит в моделе всё правильно сделал, а вот при создании дома у меня ошибка

> ErrorException
> foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/house

Я так понимаю что я сделал ошибку в foreach, но где именно, подскажите пожалуйста.

На всякий случай вот миграции

**House migration**

```php
 $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
```

**Otchet migration**

```php
$table->text('file_name');
            $table->text('link_file');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('house_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('house_id')->references('id')->on('houses');
```

Comment: Перевести ошибку не пробовали? `аргумент для foreach() должен быть массив или объект, передаётся null` - как вы думаете, в foreach ошибка?

Comment: @InDevX, Я знаю что ошибка в foreach, но не знаю где

Comment: Неверный ответ. Ошибка тут - `$request->getOtchetsForHouse`.. var_dump, или dd какой-то, вам в помощь

Comment: На сколько я понимаю я должен через $request обратится к функции в моделе House, в данный момент это у меня getOtchetForHouse, далее обернуть в $house->otchets()->create([...]);. Запросов не каких нету к данным в таблице Otchets

Comment: Что вы хотите тем foreach перебирать? Если отчеты - откуда они берутся?

Comment: @InDevX, у меня две таблицы дома (house) и отчеты (otchets). Мне надо чтобы я при создании дома, мог добавлять и отчеты в базу. С выводом не каких проблем не было, я вывел достаточно быстро данные из баз, а вот с созданием домов вышли проблемы.

Comment: А в модели house что делает getOtchetsForHouse()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
 foreach($request->getOtchetsForHouse as $otchet) {

            $house->getOtchetsForHouse()->create([
                'file_name' => $otchet['file_name'],
                'link_file' => $otchet['link_file'],
             ]);

        }
```

Заменить на

```php
        $house->getOtchetsForHouse()->create([
            'file_name' => $request->get('file_name'),
            'link_file' => $request->get('link_file')
        ]);
```